Surjective, finite-type, quasi-finite morphism that is not finite: a non-example?
Ex 3.5 (c) of Hartshorne asks to find a surjective, finite-type, quasi-finite morphism that is not finite. I came up with $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]$. My thinking is that this is surjective as a morphism of schemes because if we take an odd prime $p$, then $(\mathbb{Z}_2)_p$ is just $\mathbb{Z}_p$, it's of finite-type because $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]$ is generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra by $\frac{1}{2}$, it's quasi-finite because a prime $p \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ can only be the target of $p \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]$, and it's not finite because if $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]$ is generated by $a_i$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then taking the denominators of the $a_i$ to be at most $2^n$, then $\frac{1}{2^{(n+1)}}$ will not be generated by the $a_i$.
Now this question has already been asked here with some somewhat involved answers, which makes me think that my example must be wrong; I've been known to make stupid mistakes! Where is the error in my thinking?
Also, part (a) of that question asks to show that a finite morphism is quasi-finite. Now, all solutions I've seen of this are also somewhat involved, whereas I would just say reduce to the affine case and observe that the morphism is just the diagonal $A \rightarrow (\oplus_{i=1}^n A)/I$ for some ideal $I$, so if you give me a prime $p \subseteq A$, we only can have the finite primes $p \times A \times \ldots A$ up to $A \times \ldots \times p$ (modulo $I$) mapping to $p$. part (b) of this question just amounts to observing that if we have a closed set $V(I_1 \times \ldots I_n)$, then this is mapped to $V(I_1) \cup \ldots \cup V(I_n)$ Again, this thinking seems to good to be true given other solutions. Why am I wrong?

Think again about whether it is really surjective

The prime ideal $(2)$ is not contained in the image of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z[2^{-1}] \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$. In the localisation, $2$ is a unit, so it can never be contained in a prime ideal.

OK I guess a surjective morphism of schemes means surjective topologically. In my defence, I don't think Hartshorne gives this definition anywhere, so I assumed that a surjective morphism of schemes means that the sheaf map is surjective. Not entirely stupid mistake I suppose... Thanks @leoli1 and @Tzimmo!

Actually, regarding the second part of the question @leoli1, i.e. proving that a finite map is closed, the proofs I've seen involve using going-up, which makes sense, but can't we prove more directly as I suggest? Finite is stronger than integral after all...

@TheSpecialOne You mean showing that a finite morphism is closed? Yeah, I don't really know a proof of this that does not use concepts like integrality

@leoli1 OK thanks for this last comment; just seems strange that we need to rely on integrality given that finite is strictly stronger. Anyway I will study those proofs more closely to understand why my argument above does not work. Thanks again!
